# How to access a service from a GUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service

I have a program for collecting files from networked computers and storing them to local directories. This is done hourly, I am looking to make this into a service that will run in the background, BUT have a small app running that makes a systemtray icon, this icon would allow the user to open a GUI where they can modify the location to save the files to and the location to retrieve the files from, as well as do a manual collection of files for a user defined dateTime range. I am curious if the GUI is just a front end and all the 'heavy-lifting' methods are done in the service how can I access those service functions from GUI?
for example if the below was my service(very crude version):

```
partial class RemoteArchiveService : ServiceBase
{
   ...
   ...
   string destination;
   string retrieveFrom;
   List<string> fileNames;
   public void ChangeCollectFrom(string filepath){...}
   public void ChangeDestinationFolder(string filepath){...}
   public void GetFilesAsynchronously(){...}
   ...
   ...
}
```

in the GUI code how could I access the function ChangeCollectionFrom() with a new user input string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into WCF and make your GUI a client that calls into the service. A good place to start would be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

WCF will allow you to cleanly and concisely specify the methods that a client will need to access by hosting a WCF service in your existing windows service. For example you could do something like the following:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Somewhere.StackOverflow.Samples")]
public interface IRemoteArchive
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ChangeCollectionFrom(string filepath);
}

partial class RemoteArchiveWCFService : IRemoteArchive
{
    public void ChangeCollectionFrom(string filepath)
    {
        // ...    
    }
}
```

And then elsewhere in your RemoteArchiveService ( snippet taken from link above )

```
partial class RemoteArchiveService : ServiceBase
{
    // ...
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }

        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RemoteArchiveWCFService));

        // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
        // listening for messages.
        serviceHost.Open();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So how would I then Access the functions in the GUI? sorry, the WCF stuff is pretty confusing to me

Comment: also are the functions now contained in the RemoteArchiveWCFService in your example or are those just references to the functions/methods in the service?

Comment: I would go through the Getting Started Tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more on how WCF works and building a client. Basically your GUI would create a WCF service proxy and call into that as if it were the service object, e.g. when the user hits a save button it could call the ChangeCollectionFrom method on the proxy which would call into the service.

Comment: As far as the functions in the RemoteArchiveWCFService, you very well may be able to have your Windows service class implement the interface directly, I just haven't tried it myself and can't remember if it works off the top of my head.

Comment: I would probably spend the 1/2 hour or so it will take to go through the tutorial and create the calculator service exactly as it says, and then see if you can use the same techniques to get your windows service to be a WCF service as well.

Comment: I looked through all of the materials on WCFs but I have one issue: what do I do for a Namespace? is this something I just makeup or are these specific and important?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35095/discussion-between-darthsheldon-and-iddillian)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, most of services expose a Web UI for configuration and administration like Oracle, Network-enabled printers, etc., so I recommend you take advantage of Web UI for your purpose and the happy news is that it's not very difficult.

[Nancy](http://nancyfx.org) is a lightweight, low-ceremony, framework for building HTTP based services on .Net and Mono which can help you in this way.

In addition, [Build Simple Web UIs with the Nancy Framework](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/03/01/simple-web-uis-with-the-nancy-framework.aspx?sc_lang=en) is a great article that exactly describes what you want.